# Draw border on a ListBox control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

> PROBLEM

I'm trying to draw a border on a sub-classed ListBox's surface, I get pretty results:

[image]

But if I scroll the control, this is what happens:

[image]

> QUESTION

In **C#** or else **VB.Net**, how I could properly draw a border over the control edges like picture one?

(to clarify: not a border on each item)

> CODE

This is what I was doing:

```
public class mylistbox : inherits listbox

Public Sub New()

    MyBase.DrawMode = Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable

End Sub

Private Sub DrawBorder(ByVal g As Graphics)

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, Me.ClientRectangle, 
                                BorderColor, ButtonBorderStyle)

End Sub

Private Sub MyBase_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.DrawItem

    Me.ColorizeItems(e)

End Sub

Private Sub ColorizeItems(ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs)

    ' non important code here...

    Me.DrawBorder(Graphics.FromHwnd(Me.Handle))

End Sub

end class
```

Comment: The problem is that the DrawItem Method is called multiple times, in this case, each time you scroll .NET redraws the control. Why don't you try setting the border color property of the listbox.

Comment: why are you redrawing the *control* border when asked to paint an *item*?  The ColorizeItems code would seem to be at fault.  It should also be using the graphics object available via `DrawItemEventArgs`.

Comment: @Esteban Falcón a WinForms ListBox does not have a border color property, maybe you talk about WPF.

Comment: @Plutonix then what event I should override or to subscribe? If I don't try to draw the border when DrawItem is called then I never get see it drawn. I also thinked about processing the wm_paint message to draw the border but that message is not processed when scrolling the control.

Comment: Did you try OnPaint?  (I cant actually see a border in the pics, not enough contract for what is probably a 1 px line.  I am assuming BorderColor is light blue which is showing up between items?)

Comment: @Plutonix, I've tried it "all", seems that a Listbox never calls a OnPaint event. yes the blue line(s) is the intent of border. I have my listbox's DrawMode set as 'OwnerDrawVariable' if that matters

Comment: you might have to use WndProc since you want to paint outside ClientRectangle...unless this is a UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw on **WM_NCPAINT (133)**:

```
//
<DllImport("User32.dll")>_
Public Shared Function GetWindowDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function ReleaseDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hDC As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Dim HDC As IntPtr

    If m.Msg = 133 Then
        HDC = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd)

        If HDC <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            MyBase.WndProc(m) //call it to draw what it needs

            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(HDC)
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, Me.Width - 1, Me.Height - 1)
            End Using

            ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, HDC)

            Return
        End If
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Digging even more in *WM_NCPAINT*, you can do it like this also:

```
//
<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function ReleaseDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hDC As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Private Structure RECT
    Public Left As Integer
    Public Top As Integer
    Public Right As Integer
    Public Bottom As Integer
End Structure

<DllImport("gdi32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function CreateRectRgnIndirect(ByRef lpRect As RECT) As IntPtr
End Function


Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Dim HDC As IntPtr
    Dim rgn As IntPtr
    Dim rt As RECT
    Dim pnt As Point

    If m.Msg = 133 Then
        HDC = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd)

        pnt = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))

        rt.Left = pnt.X
        rt.Top = pnt.Y
        rt.Right = rt.Left + Me.Width - 4
        rt.Bottom = rt.Top + Me.Height - 4

        rgn = CreateRectRgnIndirect(rt)

        If HDC <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(HDC)
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0, 0, Me.Width - 1, Me.Height - 1)
            End Using

            m.WParam = rgn

            ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, HDC)
        End If
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

We are trying to create a *rect* that doesn't include the border **but** includes the vertical scrollbar. From this *rect* create a *region* and pass it to *wParam*.

Comment: thankyou, but it eats the scrollbar the first time that the control is displayed until I scroll up or down, do you have idea of how to solve it?, I mean that If you fill a listbox at design time to have a scrollbar, then  after running the project, the scrollbar is empty: http://i.imgur.com/QLO2ZMY.jpg

Comment: You have to pass MyBase.WndProc(m) for that event.  As the OP found out, the scrollbars are drawn from that message.  You have to call it first, then your drawing code, which means you will probably have a flicker problem.

Comment: @ElektroStudios You are right. I didn't notice it. Fixed

Comment: Thanks, just additional info: it does not produce any flickering in my case, maybe because as I've seen the msg is processed very few times when scrolling and not all the time.

Comment: @ElektroStudios See edit for another method without the first *hack*.

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε thankyou so much, I have a fast question, which of the two approachs will reduce more the flickering? (I have flickering sometimes when scrolling because too much drawing)

Comment: @ElektroStudios Both of these methods draw **only** the border. The flickering that the first method(not the second) might bring(what LarsTech was referring) is on the blue line **only**. You are experiencing flickering in the client area which has nothing to do with WM_NCPAINT.